# centos 7 high outbound traffic 50-80 MiB/s, trouble identifying process

Tags: linux, networking, centos7, malware

I have an updated fresh install of CentOS 7. A day after installing I noticed a ton of outbound traffic coming from it, enough to slow the whole home network down and crash my Netgear n450 router.

iftop reveals:

```
192.168.0.9:45819 => 39.107.91.147:asterix
192.168.0.9:41311 => 39.107.91.147:asterix
192.168.0.9:20364 => 39.107.91.147:asterix
192.168.0.9:43557 => 39.107.91.147:asterix
```

That destination port of asterix seems odd.  I ran `netstat` but didnt see anything related to that destination, and `lsof -i :asterix` shows nothing.

I'm willing to just wipe the whole thing and reinstall, but my curiosity wants to dig into this.  Can anyone enlighten me on how I can figure out which process is causing this and how i can remove it?

Edit:
I also ran wireshark:

```
192.168.0.9    39.107.224.31    tcp    921    54081 ->8600 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=60246 Len=867
192.168.0.9    39.107.224.31    tcp    911    28526 ->8600 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=60596 Len=857
```

and it goes on and  on, note the different destination IP, it changes everytime i reconnect or set a firewall rule to drop outbound traffic to that address.

Comment: Maybe https://superuser.com/q/603861/164903

Comment: That IP address is in China, so unless you got some business there you might wnat to unplug that thing!

Comment: @Colt , yeah I immediately disconnected the ethernet.  I only briefly reconnect it to monitor the traffic.  Crazy thing is it had already sent over 200 gigs of something during the night, no idea what its sending though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to install tools like fail2ban, OSSEC so you can monitor this kind of incidents in a more efficient way.

And then using netstat you can get user, inode etc. 
If you know the port:

```
# netstat -tanp -e |awk 'NR == 2 || /<port_number/'

Example
# netstat -tanp -e |awk 'NR == 2 || /8009/'
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      43475      8771034    30611/java
```

Comment: Thanks Tux, I'll keep that in mind.  Unfortunately I chickened out and wiped the machine, I didn't want to risk being involved in some Chinese botnet.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs), it's like the regular `top` command, but shows you per-process network utilization.